# Problemas com HTML Responsivo com ASP MVC5

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, layout-responsivo

Estou com problemas em deixar minha página responsiva, para desktop está ficando correto, como mostra a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, ao testar para mobile, fica da seguinte maneira (utilizando a ferramente no google chrome para emular a tela de um celular):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu HTML é:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
    <section id="team" class="pb-5">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-2">
                    <div class="frontside">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
                            <br>
                            <div class="card-body text-center">
                                <p><img class="img-fluid" src="~/Imagens/Menu/autorizados.jfif" alt="card image"></p>
                                <h2 class="card-title">Autorizados</h2>
                                <h5 class="card-text">Consultar o status dos autorizados cadastrados.</h5>
                                <br>
                                @if (Model.permissaoUsuario.Equals("A"))
                                {
                                <a href="~/Autorizados/Exibe" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg "><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>                                
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" disabled><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>                               
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-2">
                    <div class="frontside">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
                            <br>
                            <div class="card-body text-center">
                                <p>
                                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="~/Imagens/Menu/frota2.png" alt="card image">
                                </p>
                                <h2 class="card-title">Frota</h2>
                                <h5 class="card-text">Consultar os veículos cadastrados.</h5>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            @if (Model.permissaoUsuario.Equals("A"))
                            {
                            <center><a href="~/Frota/Exibe" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></center>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            <center><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" disabled><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></center>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-2">
                    <div class="frontside">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
                            <br>
                            <div class="card-body text-center">
                                <p><img class=" img-fluid" src="~/Imagens/Menu/nfe.png" alt="card image"></p>
                                <h2 class="card-title">Notas Fiscais</h2>
                                <h5 class="card-text">Consultar as notas fiscais emitidas e pendentes.</h5>
                                <br>
                                <a href="~/NotasFiscais/Exibe" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-2">
                    <div class="frontside">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
                            <br>
                            <div class="card-body text-center">
                                <p><img class="img-thumbnail" src="~/Imagens/Menu/fatura.png" alt="card image"></p>
                                <h2 class="card-title">Faturas</h2>
                                <h5 class="card-text">Consultar todas as faturas em aberto.</h5>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            @if (Model.permissaoUsuario.Equals("A"))
                            {
                            <center><a href="~/Faturas/Exibe" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></center>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            <center><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" disabled><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></center>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-2">
                    <div class="frontside">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
                            <br>
                            <div class="card-body text-center">
                                <p><img class=" img-fluid" src="~/Imagens/Menu/dashboard.png" alt="card image"></p>
                                <h2 class="card-title">Dashboards</h2>
                                <h5 class="card-text">Consultar gráficos de consumo e médias.</h5>
                                <br>
                                @if (Model.permissaoUsuario.Equals("A"))
                                {
                                <a href="~/Grafico/Exibe" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" disabled><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-2">
                    <div class="frontside">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
                            <br>
                            <div class="card-body text-center">
                                <p><img class="img-thumbnail" src="~/Imagens/Menu/bonus.png" alt="card image"></p>
                                <h2 class="card-title">Bônus</h2>
                                <h5 class="card-text">Consultar saldo e extrato da pontuação bônus.</h5>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <center><a href="~/PontuacaoBonus/Exibe" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
}
```

Estou na div com class="card" colocando o width= 100%, li a respeito que para deixar responsivo pode-se utilizar REM ou EM, porém não consegui resultados positivos (pode ser que utilizei da maneira errada). Teria algum jeito de consertar isso?

Comment: Vc quer que todos box tenham o mesmo tamanho independente do tamanho do conteúdo é isso?